# Coffeescript: Remove duplicate values from json object

Tags: json, coffeescript

I am new to coffee script. I know this might be very silly. But don't know how to do it.

I have a Json Object. It may have duplicate objects. How can i remove duplicates and keep unique objects only.

```
    [Object, Object, Object, Object]
    0: Object
    $$hashKey: "045"
    id: "2"
    user: "mark"
    __proto__: Object
    1: Object
    $$hashKey: "046"
    id: "3"
    user: "jason"
    __proto__: Object
    2: Object
    $$hashKey: "047"
    id: "4"
    user: "holmes"
    __proto__: Object
    3: Object
    $$hashKey: "048"
    id: "5"
    user: "peter"
    __proto__: Object
    4: Object
    $$hashKey: "04D"
    id: "4"
    user: "holmes"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

FYI : $$hashkey is not part of my json. When i console it i could see it.
Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example with duplicates? Would every field be duplicated? Would it be sufficient to just find ones with the same "$$hashKey"?

Comment: Could you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example and the expected result?

Comment: or you could just us a utility library like undersscore or lodash: `nonDupes = _(data).uniq (obj)-> obj.id` jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kskgbfy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deduplication based on `id` in "pure" coffeescript:

```
rows = [
  {id: "3", user: "jason"}
  {id: "4", user: "holmes"}
  {id: "4", user: "holmes"}
  {id: "5", user: "peter"}
]

dedup = (value for _,value of new -> @[item.id] = item for item in rows; @)
#                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                          create a new associative array (well ... "object") 
#                          using `item.id` as key. Duplicates will actually
#                          overwrite previous value for that key -- but this
#                          should be idempotent if `id` is a proper key.
console.log dedup
```

Producing:

```
[ { id: '3', user: 'jason' },
  { id: '4', user: 'holmes' },
  { id: '5', user: 'peter' } ]
```

---

If you don't like "inline object creation", and if your runtime supports [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) this might be an alternative:

```
dedup =
  (value for _,value of rows.reduce ((arr,value) -> arr[value.id] = value; arr),{})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:rows%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%24%24hashKey%3A%20%22035%22%2C%20id%3A%20%223%22%2C%20user%3A%20%22jason%22%7D%0A%20%20%7B%24%24hashKey%3A%20%22036%22%2C%20id%3A%20%224%22%2C%20user%3A%20%22holmes%22%7D%0A%20%20%7B%24%24hashKey%3A%20%22036%22%2C%20id%3A%20%224%22%2C%20user%3A%20%22holmes%22%7D%0A%20%20%7B%24%24hashKey%3A%20%22037%22%2C%20id%3A%20%225%22%2C%20user%3A%20%22peter%22%7D%0A%5D%0A%0A%23%20Convert%20to%20an%20Object%20with%20%24%24hashKey%20as%20the%20key%0A%23%20This%20will%20cause%20the%20duplicates%20to%20overwrite%20each%20other%2C%0A%23%20and%20leave%20you%20with%20only%20one%20for%20each%20%24%24hashKey%0AkeyedRows%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0Afor%20row%20in%20rows%0A%20%20keyedRows%5Brow.%24%24hashKey%5D%20%3D%20row%0A%0A%23%20Convert%20back%20to%20an%20array%0ArowsDeDupped%20%3D%20(value%20for%20key%2C%20value%20of%20keyedRows)%0A%0Aalert(JSON.stringify(rowsDeDupped%2C%20null%2C%202))) is a working example of how you might accomplish this.

```
rows = [
  {id: "3", user: "jason"}
  {id: "4", user: "holmes"}
  {id: "4", user: "holmes"}
  {id: "5", user: "peter"}
]

# Use `id` as the key
# This will cause the duplicates to overwrite each other,
# and leave you with only one for each `id`
keyedRows = {}
for row in rows
  keyedRows[row.id] = row

# Convert back to an array
rowsDeDupped = (value for key, value of keyedRows)

alert(JSON.stringify(rowsDeDupped, null, 2))
```

Note, I made the assumption that you only need to identify duplicate `id`. You'd have to take a different approach if you wanted to check all the fields instead of just this one.

Comment: @Sylvain, my Stack Overflow time for the day is just about over, so I figured I'd answer with some assumptions. You could fix that issue in my example, by replacing `keyedRows[row.$$hashKey]` with `keyedRows[row.id]`. Hopefully, that's enough to get @Erma what is needed.

Comment: Done. Hope I didn't made mistakes.